# Contact Form textarea deleting on Submission

Tags: php, forms, validation, contacts

I am working with on a contact form similar to the one shown by [Dreamweaver Tutorial](http://www.dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/dreamweaver/video/contact-form-php-validation.htm).

I have a followed his instructions fairly well except when it came to the CSS. However, after linking the form up to my site, I keep getting the validation error:

> "Please enter your message to continue"

This occurs even after I have entered a message. I have gone through his 2-part series twice and have not been able to find an answer.

My code:

```
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'Matt@matthewbrianhawn.com';
$email_subject = 'Someone Contacted You on Your Site';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('name','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'name' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
    'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Contact Form Designed by James Brand @ dreamweavertutorial.co.uk -->
<!-- Covered under creative commons license - http://dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/permissions/contact-form-permissions.htm -->

    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link href="contact/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var nameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['name']; ?>';
        var emailError = '<?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?>';
        var commentError = '<?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?>';
    </script>

</head>

  <body>

    <div id="form-main">
  <div id="form-div">
  <?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>
    <form class="form" id="form1" action="index.php" method="post">

      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>" />
        <?php if(in_array('name', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['name']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
      </p>

      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
      </p>

      <p class="text">
        <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment" ><?php echo isset($_POST['comment'])? $_POST['comment'] : ''; ?></textarea>
              <?php if(in_array('comment', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
      </p>


      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" name="submit"/>
        <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="thanks_message">
<p>Thank you for your Message!</p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>





  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your text field definition for comment you have

```
textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"
```

id change it to

```
textarea name="comment" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"
```

Thats why it sees it as empty because currently its called "text" not "comment"

Comment: Thanks a ton! I have been looking for a solution for way to long!

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because the key 'comment' doesn't exist in your `$_POST` variable.

For instance the keys of your variable `$_POST` are the name of your input form.

Just try to replace 'comment' by the name of your field ('text') in your variable `$error_messages`

Comment: Thanks a ton! I have been looking for a solution for way to long!